# Unity not locking session when closing laptop lid

Tags: unity, lock-screen, lid

Sometimes after I close my laptop's lid, the system takes a few seconds after opening the lid to ask for the password and unlock the session.

In detail:

- I close the laptop lid; system should lock session
- After some time I open laptop lid, but I can free roam around the session. It doesn't ask for password and it's not locked.
- After some time (a few seconds or even a couple of minutes) the session eventually locks and asks for password, while I'm using the computer.

Here are my computer specs through screenfetch:

```
$ screenfetch -n
david@Asus-D541S
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.10.0-42-generic
Uptime: 7h 41m
Packages: 2591
Shell: bash 4.3.48
Resolution: 1366x768
DE: Unity 7.4.0
WM: Compiz
WM Theme: Ambiance
Ambiance [GTK2]
Ambiance [GTK3]
Icon Theme: Ambiant-MATE
Font: Ubuntu 11
CPU: Intel Celeron CPU N3060 @ 2.48GHz
GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 400 (Braswell) 
RAM: 2936MiB / 3773MiB
```

Comment: Check your power settings. All-Settings->Power->Screen-Brightness and enable lock.